# Get UITableView separatorColor from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

Is there an easy way to get the `separatorColor` of the `UITableView` of a `UITableViewCell` from within `-[UITableViewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]`?

I'm asking because I'm using `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]` and want to add a vertical divider to the `UITableViewCell` that is the same color as it's `tableView`'s `separatorColor`.

Answer (score 3):

As the separator views are managed by the UITableView, UIKit doesn't expose the colour to UITableViewCells. Separator insets are configurable by the cell, however, because only the cell should have knowledge about its layout which might change the insets required.

I'd suggest passing in the colour when configuring your cell, either in `-[UITableView tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` or `-[UITableView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is.

Although, there is `-[UITableViewCell separatorInsets]`.

I'd recommend hard coding `tableView.separatorColor` with whatever `UIColor` you want and using the same `UIColor` in `-[UITableViewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]`.